# 2d Maze How to Not Move Into a Wall or Out of Bounds?

Tags: java

Hi I've made my code but the only problem I'm having is to not move when there is a wall or out of bounds. The hard way I understand to do that is coding something like

`if (CHARACTER == line [2][0] && (dir.equalsIgnoreCase("l")) {}`.

(`"l"` being left) this way it won't move in that certain spot when the player wants to go left because there's a wall, but I'd have to do this for all cases and it seems pretty tedious. Any help on how to do this? Thanks.

Here's part of it if it helps:

```
private final static char CHARACTER = 'X';
private final static char BLANK = '.';
private final static char GOAL = 'O';
private final static char WALL = 'W';

private final static int SIZE = 4;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    char[][] line = new char[SIZE][SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < line.length; i++) 
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < line[i].length; j++) 
        {
            line[i][j] = BLANK;
        }
    }

    line[2][0] = CHARACTER;
    line[0][0] = GOAL;
    line[1][0] = WALL;
    line[1][1] = WALL;
    line[1][3] = WALL;
    line[2][1] = WALL;
    line[2][3] = WALL;
    int xPos = 2;
    int yPos = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can work with indices to check if you're out of bounds or if there's a wall. I'd suggest something like this (Note: This only works with Java 7 or higher)

```
// I assume your board is always square because of new char[SIZE][SIZE]
private static boolean isOutOfBounds(int coord) {
    return coord < 0 || coord >= SIZE;
}

/**
 * Checks, if the given coordinate is inside bounds and is not a wall.
 */
private static boolean isValid(int x, int y) {
    return !isOutOfBounds(x) &&
           !isOutOfBounds(y) &&
           line[x][y] != WALL;
}

// I assume you have directions "u", "r", "d", "l"
public static boolean canGoDirection(String direction, int currX, int currY) {
    switch(direction) {
        case "u": return isValid(currX, currY - 1);
        case "r": return isValid(currX + 1, currY);
        case "d": return isValid(currX, currY + 1);
        case "l": return isValid(currX - 1, currY);
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException(direction + " is not a valid direction.");
    }
}
```

Now you can use `canGoDirection()` with your current coordinates and the direction you want. If it returns `true`, you can go that way and update your new position.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand from your question is that your player should not move if the next position is a wall. Assuming that starting position of the player is not wall.

I think you must be having some way to track the players current position. In the main loop of game keep this two index update. Check the array value for the next position if it is wall than do not move(do not update the index). If not then move and update the index for users current position.